# Replacing the search-bar of a WordPress theme with another one

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

First of all, I'd like to say that my knowledge is highly limited, as you'd find out yourself.

I'm using a theme that's using its own searchbar, however I have decided that I prefer to use another one - AJAX Search Form

Now, if i hide the div with id "search-box" as shown below I'd be able to make the current searchform non-visible

```
#search-box{
display:none;
}
```

However, if I try adding the new ajax searchbar as a widget to the main header area (where the searchbar is) nothing really happens.

Therefore, I have decided to implement the search bar via PHP and that's why I've created a child-theme.

As the AJAX search bar documentations suggests, in order to add the search bar to my theme i need to add this piece of code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wcas-search-form]'); ?>
```

My question is could you please hint me where should that piece of code go and if i need to create a new file in the child-theme what functions should I be looking to replace?

This is the main theme searchform.php file:

.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template for displaying search form
 *
 * @package ThemeHunk
 * @subpackage Top Store
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
?>
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url( '/' )); ?>">
    <div class="form-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr__('search..', 'top-store' ); ?>" name="s" id="s" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr__('Search', 'top-store' ); ?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the main theme search.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package ThemeHunk
 * @subpackage  Top Store
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
get_header();
$top_store_pages_sidebar = top_store_pages_sidebar(); ?>
     <div id="content" class="page-content">
            <div class="content-wrap" >
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="main-area <?php echo esc_attr($top_store_pages_sidebar);?>">
                          <?php if($top_store_pages_sidebar !=='no-sidebar' && $top_store_pages_sidebar !=='disable-left-sidebar'){get_sidebar('primary');}?>
                        <div id="primary" class="primary-content-area">
                            <div class="primary-content-wrap">
                                 <?php
            if( have_posts()): ?>
            <?php
                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    /*
                     * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' );
                endwhile;
                
            else :
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
            endif;
            ?>
                           </div> <!-- end primary-content-wrap-->
                        </div> <!-- end primary primary-content-area-->
                         <?php if($top_store_pages_sidebar !=='no-sidebar' && $top_store_pages_sidebar !=='disable-right-sidebar'){ get_sidebar('secondary');}?>
                    </div> <!-- end main-area -->
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end content-wrap -->
     </div> <!-- end content page-content -->
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Thank you in advance.